# What does 'Reverse' means in errors when running Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a blog build with `django` on the browser. And I got this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /   
Reverse for 'blog.views.post_detail' not found.
'blog.views.post_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

My **url.py** of my app looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail),
]
```

It seems that when I type **127.0.0.1:8000/**.
The url will direct to `views.post_list`.
And my **views.py** looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts}

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

`post_list()` will render the request with **post_list.html**.
Inside **post_list.html**, the error comes from the line:

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'blog.views.post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

I don't really understand what 'Reverse' means in the error message. 'blog.views.post_detail' does exist in **views.py**. I think I got everything needed for the code and can't figure out what went wrong.

I'm new to django, sorry if the question is basic and thanks for answering!

Comment: maybe take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453368/noreversematch-at-product-pussyes-reverse-for-basket-adding-not-found-bask)

Comment: Where do you define the URL for post_detail, which you want to link to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django 1.10 removed the ability to reverse urls by the view's dotted import path. Instead, you need to name your url pattern and use that name to reverse the url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
]
```

And in your template:

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

Comment: @Zhemy See [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls). The `url` template tag calls `reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your urls.py should be as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail),
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I did have the second line of url() in my code, but I thought it was not important here and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a name for your url:

```
urlpatterns [
   url(r'^$', views.post_list,name=post_list),
]
```

then use url tag like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'AppName:post_list' %}"></a>
```

AppName is you django application name.

Comment: It says " 'blog' is not a registered namespace", where can I check my namespace? And what did the namespace actually stands for?

Comment: did you add your app in django setting file in INSTALLED_APPS=[ ] ?

Comment: Also you have to add your app to urls.py file of your djago project(not urls.py in your App)

Comment: I did. I added 'blog' in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: In my urls.py in my project, I wrote: `url(r'', include('blog.urls'))`. Is it right?

Comment: you should add your app name like: url(r'blog/', include('blog.urls'))

Comment: An URL namespace is _not_ your django application name, nor does it have anything to do with `INSTALLED_APPS`. URL namespaces are an entirely separate feature and are set using the [`app_name` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).