# I'm having a no reverse match in django for my signup

Tags: python, django

```
Environment:




 Request Method: POST
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fir/signup/

    Django Version: 1.11.12
    Python Version: 2.7.14
    Installed Applications:
    ['fir.apps.MusicConfig',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Template error:
    In template C:\Users\dell\Desktop\BlrCityPolice\fir\templates\fir\acc_active_email.html, error at line 6
       Reverse for 'activate' not found. 'activate' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

```
       1 : {% autoescape off %}
       2 : Hi {{ user.username }},
       3 : 
       4 : Please click on the link below to confirm your registration:
       5 : 
       6 : http://{{ domain }} {% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %} 
       7 : {% endautoescape %}
```

Traceback:`

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\BlrCityPolice\fir\views.py" in signup
  426.                 'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  40.         output = self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  458.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /fir/signup/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'activate' not found. 'activate' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Please help me resolve the error and here is my urls.py for activating account.

urls.py

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.activate, name='activate'),
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            message = render_to_string('fir/acc_active_email.html', {
                'user':user,
                'domain':current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            # Sending activation link in terminal
            # user.email_user(subject, message)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration.')
            # return render(request, 'acc_active_sent.html')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'fir/signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login to your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Comment: show your `view` pls

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453368/noreversematch-at-product-pussyes-reverse-for-basket-adding-not-found-bask

Comment: is your `app` well-registered in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: you have only uidb64 parameter in your url that means only one parameter but in your template you are passing two parameters uidb64 and token

Comment: @AbiWaqas, I don't think so, look: `Exception Value: Reverse for 'activate' not found. 'activate' is not a valid view function or pattern name` which means Django doesn't find this `url_name`,  so I think this is because she did not register the `app` in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @Chiefir I have included views.py

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes. It is.

Comment: @AbiWaqas I have included it. INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'fir.apps.MusicConfig', ...... ]

Comment: is that `MusicConfig` the name of your app? or `fir.apps.MusicConfig`?

Comment: try change this `{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %} ` into this `{% url 'activate' uid token %}` in your template file

Comment: @AfreenKhan as far I know you can't register an app with its path, you just have to enter the name of the app as a string into `INSTALLED_APPS` list

Comment: @Chiefir still getting the same error.

Comment: @Lemayzeur so should I change that statement?

Comment: yes, instead of `fir.apps.MusicConfig`, type `MusicConfig` . I suppose that your app name is `MusicConfig`

Comment: @Lemayzeur I guess you are right that app is not registered but she will eventually will face that error cus she has one parameter in url parameters and she is passing two

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

with

```
{% url 'your_app_name:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

Comment: Please apply https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and also explain why and how this helps.