# NoReverseMatch at 'url' in Django, Reverse for 'my_app' not found. 'my_app' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I'm new to Django, and today when I tried to run a website with a database, I have encountered this error.
I have searched for all solutions on StackOverflow and Django documents, but I can not fix it.

[This is the problem that similar to me, but it doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453368/noreversematch-at-product-pussyes-reverse-for-basket-adding-not-found-bask)

I want to create a link that moves user from **user.html in user** to **index.html in citizens**

Here is my project structure. I'm sorry because I can't attach an image, so I will try to explain it in easiest way.

**[MYPROJECT]**

->**manage.py**

->**citizens** (folder)

-->templates (inside this folder I have citizen.html, **index.html**, layout.html)

-->admin.py

-->models.py

-->tests.py

-->urls.py

-->views.py

->**myproject** (folder)

-->setting.py

-->urls.py

-->etc that I think not important

->**user** (folder)

-->templates (inside this folder I have login.html, **user.html**, layout.html)

-->urls.py

-->views.py

-->etc that I think not important

As you can see, I have **user.html** inside templates folder of user, and **index.html** inside templates folder of citizens.

Here is my code:

**index.html inside citizens**

```
{% extends "citizens/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Hệ thống quản lý XNC</h1>
    
    <table class="table">
        
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Số TT</th>
            <th scope="col">Họ và tên công dân</th>
            <th scope="col">Giới tính</th>
            <th scope="col">Số Hộ chiếu</th>
            <th scope="col">Chi tiết</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for citizen in citizens %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td>{{ citizen.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ citizen.sex }}</td>
            <td>{{ citizen.sID }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'citizen' forloop.counter %}">Truy cập</a></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        
    </table>

    
{% endblock %}
```

**user.html inside user**

```
{% extends "users/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Chào mừng, {{ request.user.username }}</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Username: {{request.user.username }}</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'citizen:citizens/' %}">Truy cập Cơ sở dữ liệu</a>
        
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py inside citizens**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:citizen_id>", views.citizen, name="citizen"),
    #path("<int:citizen_id>/passports", views.passport, name="passports")
]
```

**views.py inside citizens**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Citizen 

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "citizens/index.html", {
        "citizens": Citizen.objects.all()
    })

def citizen(request, citizen_id):
    try:
        citizen = Citizen.objects.get(sID=citizen_id)
    except Citizen.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Citizen not found")
    return render(request, "citizens/citizen.html", {
        "citizen": citizen,
        
        
    })
```

**urls.py inside myproject**

```
"""htql2 URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('citizens/', include('citizens.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
]
```

**urls.py inside users**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    
]
```

**views.py inside users**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse

@csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))
    return render(request, "users/user.html")    

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "users/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid credentials."
            }) 
    else:
        return render(request, "users/login.html")        

def logout_view(request):
    pass
```

Inside **user.html**, I have tried to use

```
<a href="{% url 'citizen:citizens/' %}">Go to Database</a>
```

but doesn't work.

Thank you. I'm so grateful.

Comment: "my_app" was only defined in one (1) block of code. Why include all the other code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to use `{% url 'citizen:citizens/' %}` here the part before `:` (`citizen`) is a url namespace and the part after it (`citizens`) is the url name. But you haven't used any namespace, and neither do you have a url name as `citizens`.

You can add a namespace in `citizens.urls` by specifying `app_name`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'citizens' # here
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:citizen_id>", views.citizen, name="citizen"),
    #path("<int:citizen_id>/passports", views.passport, name="passports")
]
```

Next you need to write the url tag as `{% url 'citizens:index' %}`:

```
<a href="{% url 'citizens:index' %}">Go to Database</a>
```

Comment: I have named all the URLs with {name="example"}. Can you explain to me the difference between "name" and "namespace" in this case?  And can namespace replace name? Thank you.

Comment: @hoangphi01 This documentation explains it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#introduction